# How to render a ReactJS component to HTML string with Node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When running this code with `node server.js`:

```
var React = require('react');

var HelloMessage = React.createClass({displayName: "HelloMessage",
    render: function() {
        return React.createElement("div", null, "Hello ", this.props.name);
    }
});

var markup = React.renderComponentToString(HelloMessage({name: "John"}));

console.log(markup);
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/john/Sites/test/server.js:9
        return React.createElement("div", null, "Hello ", this.props.name);
                     ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createElement'
```

I think it's not working because the DOM is not available on the server, which makes sense.

**How can I render/compile a ReactJS component to an HTML string in Node?**

Thanks

Comment: What version of `react` do you have installed? That exact code prints `<div data-reactid=".9zpzkvv9c0" data-react-checksum="-1155126098"><span data-reactid=".9zpzkvv9c0.0">Hello </span><span data-reactid=".9zpzkvv9c0.1">John</span></div>` for me.

Comment: What a school boy error, that was exactly it. I was running 0.10.0 but after upgrading to 0.12.2 it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to upgrade ReactJS to 0.12.2